# React-Formik set Field value in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

How do i set formik field values with values returned from the Api

calling/main page

```
return (

<Formik
  initialValues={{
    ClientId: '',
    CompanyId: '',
    InvoiceNumber: '',
    InvoiceDate: Date.parse('1985-10-20'),
    PaymentStatusId: '',
    PaymentTerms: '',
    Total: '',
    Notes: '',
    InvoiceDetails: [{
      Id: '',
      Description: '',
      Quantity: '',
      Amount: '',
      VatPercentage: '',
      VatAmount: '',
      Total: ''
    }]
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    InvoiceNumber: Yup.string().required(),
    InvoiceDate: Yup.string().required(),
  })
  }
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  }}
>

  {({ errors, touched,props }) => (
    <Container>
      <Form>


              <Field name="InvoiceNumber" component={InvoiceNumberV2} value={InvoiceNumber}/>
);
```

custom component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Api from './Api';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const InvoiceNumberV2 = ({
    field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
        form: { touched, errors,setFieldValue }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
        ...props
    }) => {

    const [invoiceNumber, setInvoiceNumber] = useState("");
    const apiurl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
    const { invoicenumber } = useParams();

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        async function a() {
            try {
                let invTemp = invoicenumber;

                if (invTemp) { }
                else {
                    const uri = `${apiurl}/invoice/getNextInvoiceNumber`;
                    let result = await Api.GetApiData(uri, true);
                    invTemp = result.data.InvoiceNumber

                    //how do I set the field value with value from invTemp???
                }
                
               
                
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }

        a();
       


    },[])


    return (
        <>
            <Form.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                Inv. number
            </Form.Label>
            <Col md={4}>
                <input type="text" column="lg"
                    lg={2} {...field} {...props}                   />
                {touched[field.name] &&
                    errors[field.name] && <div className="text-danger">{errors[field.name]}</div>}
            </Col>
        </>
    );
}

export default InvoiceNumberV2;
```

Tried doing this and it works(as in the textbox displays the correct value but Yup validation complains about the value not being found)

```
    <input type="text" column="lg"
                    lg={2} {...field} {...props}           value={invoiceNumber}        />
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I fixed it

the custom component got changed to this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Api from './Api';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Formik, useField, Form, Field, useFormikContext } from "formik";

const InvoiceNumberV3 = ({field}) => {

    const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0()
    const [invoiceNumber, setInvoiceNumber] = useState("");
    const apiurl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
    const { invoicenumber } = useParams();
    const formikProps = useFormikContext()

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        async function a() {


            let invTemp = invoicenumber;

            if (invTemp) { }
            else {
                const uri = `${apiurl}/invoice/getNextInvoiceNumber`;
                let token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
                let result = await Api.GetApiData(uri, token);
                invTemp = result.data.InvoiceNumber
            }

            setInvoiceNumber(invTemp);

            formikProps.setFieldValue("InvoiceNumber", invTemp)
        }
        a();
    },[])

    
        return (
        <>
            <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                Inv. number
            </FormControl.Label>
            <Col md={4}>
                    <FormControl.Control
                    type="text"
                    column="lg"
                    lg={2}
                    readOnly={true}
                    {...field}
                />
            </Col>
        </>
    );
}

export default InvoiceNumberV3;
```

the page that calls the component got changed to this.. Only keeping the relevant parts

```
.....
return (

    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        InvoiceNumber: '',
        InvoiceDate: Date.parse('1985-10-20'),
        ClientId: '',
        CompanyId: '',
        PaymentStatusId: '',
        PaymentTerms: '',
        Total: '',
        Notes: '',
        InvoiceDetails: [{
          Id: '',
          Description: '',
          Quantity: '',
          Amount: '',
          VatPercentage: '',
          VatAmount: '',
          Total: ''
        }]
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        InvoiceNumber: Yup.string().required(),
        InvoiceDate: Yup.string().required(),
        ClientId: Yup.string().required(),
        CompanyId: Yup.string().required(),
      })
      }
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
      }}
    >



      {/* {({ errors, touched,props }) => ( */}
      {props => (
        <Container>
          <Form>

            {!invoicenumber && <h1 className="header text-center">Create new invoice</h1>}
            {invoicenumber && <h1 className="header text-center">Edit invoice</h1>}


            {!isAuthenticated && <Login></Login>}
            {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}

            {success && <Alert variant="success">{success}</Alert>}

            <Row>

              <Field name="InvoiceNumber" component={InvoiceNumberV3} />

           </Row>
 .....


  </Form>  
        </Container>      
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Invoice;
```